# ASP Net Gridview HyperLinkField to navigate to URL form database

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

In my database I have a table with a list of websites and names. I need to populate my gridview HyperLinkField with the names, and each name linking to its correspondnig URL in the database.

In the past I've done this for a simple query linking to another page in my own site, but I can't find anything for what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: you need to show some code if you need help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming items in your datasource has two properties `WebsiteName` and `Link`.
Now try this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="Server" id="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
       <asp:HyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Links" DataNavigateUrlField="Link" DataTextField="WebsiteName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```